# Where to encounter zombies?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've been on two terrifying biomes so far, but haven't encountered any zombies. Are there other conditions that are needed for zombies to be present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Surroundings#Evil) tells us that about half of all evil regions are reanimating. That is, creatures originating in them are all undead and dead creatures reanimate within them. There are also [evil weather](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Weather#Evil_weather) effects that can produce husks which are kind of like zombies. The wiki says that most evil regions have evil weather, but only some evil weather will produce husks.

If you haven't encountered zombies yet (and you want to), then you have probably been just a bit unlucky. However embarking in another part of the same evil region will not change whether it has zombies or not, you need to find a different region to try. The regions are often given names in the embark screen, like "The Sunny Hills", or "The Plains of Wounding". If you are looking at a region with the same name it will likely give you the same result.

One way to ensure that you encounter zombies eventually (if your fort lasts long enough), is to embark near a [necromancer's](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Necromancer) tower. If you embark close enough to a tower the necromancer can decide to lay siege to your fortress(unless invaders are turned off in the config file). They tend to bring zombies with them, and create more on site.

Hopefully this helps a bit. Dealing with the random number generator can be frustrating at times.

Comment: Embarking near a necromancer's tower is probably the only guaranteed way of encountering zombies. However, very young worlds are less likely to have necromancers and thus fewer necromancer towers. Make sure you generate a world with a history of at least 100 years.